# Injecting Custom Args using Method Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

I am newbie to Ninject. I have seen Constructor Injection with Custom Arguments can be done by using

```
Bind<>().To<>().WithConstructorArguments("Name","Value")
```

Then I thought to, try a sample of Method Injection with some custom arguments like as below:

```
[Inject]
public void DoSomething(int a,string data,double b, etc...)
{

}
```

But, I got tucked on how to pass data, to those arguments..

I have checked the intellisense and seen functions like, WithConstructorArgument, WithPropertyValue and so I believed there should/may be a option to achieve this one..

May I know, how to solve this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use method injection like that. What you can do, however, is using the `OnActivation` extension like:

```
Bind<>().To<>()
    .OnActivation(x => x.DoSomething(5, "hello world", 3.5,...);
```

It gets executed after ninject calls the ctor and perform property / method injection. So exactly once per instance. Effectively this should just be what you're looking for.